# Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL <-- there aren't any redirects

Tags: java, android, http, redirect, jsoup

**Code:**

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.warriorforum.com/").followRedirects(true).get();
```

**Log cat error:**

```
10-14 11:58:08.593: ERROR/MY(24780): TRY1: download failed java.io.IOException: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL http://www.warriorforum.com/
```

As you can see in [Jsoup Connection class](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.java) the exception is thrown in `private Response(Response previousResponse) throws IOException` when redirect count exceeds `private static final int MAX_REDIRECTS = 20;`

Worked about 12h ago fine, but something has changed on the host side and I can't figure out what. When viewing the url with browser, there doesn't seem to be any redirects. What is causing this error?

**EDIT** - accessing subforums and topics with `Jsoup.connect(url).get()` is working, but not the main page.

Comment: Get [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) out and see if there are any redirects. Either the server is getting stuck in a redirect loop, or your code is wrong. If there are indeed no redirects and it worked before and now doesn't - maybe try re-compiling? If there are redirects from Java, but not from a browser, look at exactly what headers are being exchanged, and try and mimic the browser exactly from Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I open the URL in my browser (Chrome), I get "This webpage has a redirect loop". It responds with a 301 and the very same URL as the new Location (http://www.warriorforum.com/).

Maybe the website is still cached in the browser? Maybe the redirect depends on client specifics (like language, country, browser, ...)?

Comment: That's very interesting, I'm using Chrome also but I don't see any notification about "redirect loop" (cleared my browser cache).

Comment: I managed to see a redirect loop message once when I opened the website with Firefox. The second time it didn't occur and nor does it occur with Chrome/IE. Do modern browsers have some kind of redirect-loop handling functionality? How  can I reproduce that error to show administrators of that website?

Comment: I noticed that if I hit Ctrl + F5 in Chrome the site will load (and a cookie is set, so best is to use the incognito mode while testing). The difference is, that this will send `Cache-Control: no-cache` as well as `Pragma: no-cache` headers in the request, which forces proxies to forward the request to the original server. So it looks like one of their proxies is misconfigured. If you can set these cache headers with JSoup you probably don't have to rely on them fixing their configuration.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Excellent answer! Are there negative effects when I use the `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Pragma: no-cache` on my other sites with Jsoup *just in case* to avoid future problems with misconfigured proxies?

Comment: A main drawback is that the performance can be worse if cached versions cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) to take a snapshot/trace of when it happens, then you can send it to the admins of the site for them to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and as all ways I came to source to figure it out. 
So reading others complain about similar issues I've figure it out (smart ass) and here it is for anyone likes too many opinions.
As the issue is clearly a loop issue, it has to do with the web site request and your browser's cache  (authentication session perhaps).
In my case there was no internal (website ) router (rewrites or similar case) and solve it by scale the request. Otherwise a clean browsers cache might solve the issue otherwise clean all cookies (session) that related to this domain. Doesn't heart to check with other browsers if available. If different browsers have the same issue and your cache is clean (as...) and the web page request is clean (headers POST/GET/PUT ctr) then it's out of your hands. Give it up.
Check an other web page. It's a vast field out there.
P.S. Good morning stackoverflowers !!!